# Error when trying to programmatically create columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am getting this error when I try to create a new column in a `data.table` programmatically:

```
dt[, (new_x) := get(x)]
# Error in get(x) : invalid first argument
```

Where `x` is a variable that holds the name of the column that I am using in the assignment, which also happens to be named `"x"` in this case. In other words, `x <- "x"`, and `"x" %in% names(dt)` is `TRUE`. This error only seems to occur when the variable name is the same as the column name.

A reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)

# Our data.table
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
dt
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# ...

# My new column name
new_col <- "new_column"
# Will make my new column be the sum of two columns
mpg <- "mpg"
cyl <- "cyl"

# I thought this would work:
dt[, (new_col) := get(mpg) + get(cyl)]
# Error in get(mpg) : invalid first argument

# If the variable names are not the same as the string it contains, it works
mpg_col <- "mpg"
cyl_col <- "cyl"
dt[, (new_col) := get(mpg_col) + get(cyl_col)]
```

Now, in my script, I have a helper function that takes in two column names, `x` and `y`, as arguments to calculate a new column with name `new_col`.

```
calculate_new_column <- function(dt, x, y, new_col) { 
  dt[, (new_col) := some calculation with x and y ]
}
```

Is there a way to make my function safe to this kind of corner case, where `x = 'x'` or `y = 'y'`? I guess I could give unique names to the arguments of the function (e.g. `.x.` and `.y.`), but would prefer a better solution.

**EDIT**

Following my reproducible example, it seems this works:

```
dt[, (new_col) := get(eval(mpg)) + get(eval(cyl))]
```

But I am wary of using `eval` and am not sure if this follows best practices. Would this be the way to go?

Comment: I think `eval` is the best solution due to scoping: [`look 2.8`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf).

Comment: `get` takes a character string, like `get("mpg")`

Comment: My practice (not sure if it's best) aligns with your third way: use verbose names for my "variable containing variable names", like `my_cols = c("mpg","cyl")` so I can do `DT[, (new_col) := Reduce("+", .SD), .SDcols = my_cols]`

Comment: @m0nhawk Thanks for the reference to the scoping rules in the data.table FAQs.

Comment: @Frank Makes sense. Though in my actual function, it is not a simple addition operation, but a more complex calculation. It would not fit in a `Reduce`, but I like that suggestion of using `.SDcols`.

Comment: Variables are looked first within the scope of your data.table, and within the scope, columns are seen as variables; i.e., `get(mpg)` first looks at `mpg` from your data.table.